# how to balance training data using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have gathered some train dataset to train the network model, but unfortunately the dataset is critically unbalanced is there a way to balancing the data using Keras library without the need to balance it manually (dataset of two objects: object 1 2000 data while the other is 15000 ) , I don't want to use upsampling or downsampling cause I don't want to get problems in overfitting or underfitting

Comment: Take a look at this blog: https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-imbalanced-datasets-in-deep-learning-f48407a0e758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways and best-practices to deal with so called *imbalanced* data sets.

- **Upsample** the minority class (Drawback: possibly overfitting of minority class)
- **Downsample** the majority class (Drawback: loss of training data, information loss)

There are a number of techniques you can use for this, some even offer methods to overcome drawbacks (e.g. synthetic sampling). Have a look at the [`imbalanced-learn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) package for a easy-to-use implementation.

Another thing you could use is to **weight the loss of your model** in order to tell the model that it should "pay more attention" to specific classes. This can be easily done by defining the optional argument `class_weight` in keras `fit` function. The class weights can be easily computed by sklearns [`compute_class_weight`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) function.